# Unexpected T function error in wordpress code

Tags: php

Hi I keep getting an Unexpected T_function error on the last line when i run the below code on a webserver running php 5.2, this runs fine on my local machine running php 5.3.6

```
 // ***** Declare function that buids the post type
 function add_post_type($name, $args = array() ) {
    add_action('init',function() use($name, $args) {
```

can somebody help me spot whats wrong?

Comment: Fixed it, apparently this is a mirror of another question. apologies.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The piece of code:

```
function() use($name, $args) { ..
```

it's an **anonymous function** (or closure).
[Anonymous functions](http://php.net/manual/en/functions.anonymous.php) are avaiable since **PHP 5.3.0**

Answer (score 1):

Anonymous functions aren't available until PHP 5.3. [See the changelog](http://php.net/manual/en/functions.anonymous.php).

Answer (score 0):

PHP 5.2 doesn't support anonymous functions